# tensorflow model: what is the difference between .data-00000-of-00002 and ,data-00001-of-00002?

Tags: tensorflow, model, store

When storing a tensorflow ckpt, besides the .index, .meta and checkpoint files, there are two ".data" files saved at the same time: .data-00000-of-00002 and .data-00001-of-00002. The former's size is much smaller than the latter's. My question is, why there are two data files saved and what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to tensorflow official [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load):
One or more shards (`<prefix>-<global_step>.data-<shard_index>-of-<number_of_shards>`) contain model's weights and index file contains which weights are stored in which shard. Number of shards depend on how many machines you are using for training.

Therefore, if you train a model on two machines, you'll have two shards with the suffix: `.data-00000-of-00002` and `.data-00001-of-00002`

You may want to check out [this url](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-saving-restoring-and-mixing-multiple-models-c4c94d5d7125) too.

While instantiating `tf.train.Saver`, you can set the value of argument `sharded` (default value is `False`). `sharded=True` instructs Saver to shard checkpoints for each machine/device.